# Writing inside the image as in the Figure

Tags: graphics

I have set my image as you see in the attached figure, is it possible to do so in Latex? and how ?  [image: editing the diagram]

Comment: Several methods are shown here: [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559)

Comment: great link  and useful